# Open command prompt using an exe file and print the contents in it

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10, exe

I'm trying to create an exe file and I have a set of print statements in my code.

[This is the exe file that I have created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djVAI.png)
When I run that file, nothing pops-up (like cmd) and just the code runs in the background. I want that process to be visible in the command prompt.

What is the code snippet that I need to include in my program to make my exe file open the command prompt and then print those statements?

I'm new to python and tried searching for this, but couldn't get any.

Below is the sample code that I'm using:

```
with open("NC_connections_check.txt", 'w') as file_write:
    file_write.write("Below are the NC connections in the sch:\nKindly go through each line and verify in your sch\n\n")
    for key in text_dict:
        file_write.write("======================================================\n")
        for v in range(len(text_dict[key])):
            file_write.write("{}.{}, ".format(key, text_dict[key][v]))
        file_write.write("\n")

os.remove("intermediate_file.txt")
print("NC pin connections check completed\n\nKindly check the NC_connections_check.txt file")
```

i want the print() statement line to be printed on the command prompt while running the .exe file

Comment: What code is implemented in your exe file? Please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How did you create the exe, which tools were used with which parameters?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I have followed the process that was mentioned in the following link. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/

Answer (score 1):

From the comment you posted, it appears like you're using the `-w` flag in pyinstaller, which causes the program to run without the console (only shows the window, but since your program is console only nothing appears). Remove the `-w` flag from your build command and rebuild the .exe file.

[Source from pyinstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-w)